# How to subtract two Prometheus metrics to calculate the duration of pod execution?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, prometheus, monitoring

Im trying to get the pods runnig time from the created moment to the termination
after tryin hunderd solution I think Im close
I have this query gives me when pod terminated

```
 last_over_time(timestamp(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Succeeded",pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"})[1h:])
```

and this gives me when pod is  created

```
last_over_time((kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1h]))
```

but when I put **-** between them I get empty **Empty query result**
What I can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution this query worked and it return the runnig  period for each pod

```
last_over_time(timestamp(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Succeeded",pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"})[1h:])
  - ignoring(phase) group_right()
  last_over_time((kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1h:]))
```